# What is the purpose of the Load transistor in a TTL Logic NOT gate?

Tags: mosfet, ttl

My professor presented the NOT gate in the Transistor-Transistor logic as the following:

[image]

Where V is always 5Volts. The two symbols are MOSFETs N-type transistors. The first transistor (which is always conducting) is called the Load transistor, and the second is the one who really does the logic operations. (By first I mean the top one, and second the bottom one).

What I'm unable to understand is why does this Load transistor exists. Can't we just plug the Drain of the other transistor directly in V? Why do we have to add a transistor between them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*Can't we just plug the Drain of the other transistor directly in V*", then where would the output be?

Comment: This is not transistor-transistor logic (TTL), it is depletion load NMOS logic.

Comment: I also question why some professors still talk about obsolete logic types like this. I mean, depletion transistors, for logic, no-one uses that anymore. It is not like CMOS is difficult to understand.

Comment: Bimpelrekkie, we had a brief tour in the old logic types (like this one) before studying CMOS logic properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare these two circuits:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyPUL0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In which one(s) do you think the meters VM1 and VM2 can be made to show a voltage other than V = 0 Volt ?

In circuit A the NMOS1 can conduct some current so that the voltage at "out" can increase. Then VM1 can show a voltage larger than 0 Volts.

I think that in circuit B there is no chance **at all** of the meter VM2 showing anything but V = 0 Volt. Do you agree?

**Update**

OP suggested this as a "fix"for circuit B to make it work again

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fodJYN.png)</sup>

Look carefully at the circuit, note how Drain-Source of NMOS3 and VM2 are **in parallel** with the battery. The battery is ideal, it outputs Vbat, no matter what. Can NMOS3 then still influence the voltage across VM2?

Also note how "out" is now **directly connected** to the battery, so what can we then say about the voltage at "out"?

Comment: I do. But what if I connected the + pole of the Bat to the drain of de NMOS3 in Circuit B? (Something like switching from NMOS1 to an closed circuit in Circuit A)

Comment: *what if I connected the + pole of the Bat to the drain of de NMOS3 in Circuit B* Well, think about it! What would VM2 show. It is now in parallel with the battery so.... And what can NMOS3 do? Note that the battery is an "ideal" battery, it can supply as much current as anyone needs while still keeping its nominal voltage across its terminals.

Comment: I think that this is precisely the problem: I can't see the practical difference between an closed wire and an always-conducting transistor. For me in the case I suggested the circuit would work as a NOT gate, since when Vin = HIGH NMOS3 would conduct and VM2 wouldn't be parallel with the battery no more.

Comment: *...and VM2 wouldn't be parallel with the battery no more.* How is that possible? I will draw the circuit change you proposed in my answer.

Comment: I appreciate your help, sincerely.

Comment: Now I can see that Vout will always be the same voltage as the Battery. Thank you!
But then it comes another problem: I can't see how the NMOS1 in circuit A changes that. Since it will always be conducting, for me it doesn't change a thing. I can't see how the circuit A can yeld a LOW output.
I'm sorry for the trouble, I am no electrical/computer engineer and this is my first course ever in anything involving digital systems.

Comment: In the first circuit, NMOS1 is conducting, but is not a short circuit.  NMOS1 will act like a resistor to limit the current drawn from the battery, so it will let NMOS2 pull the output Low, and will pull the output High when NMOS2 is not conducting.